# Filter dictionary and remove lowest values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary as below. Is there a way to output a dictionary with the 5 highest values?

If there are ties for the 5th highest value, I need to include those keys.

**Input dictionary**:

```
{
    "1": 1,
    "12": 1,
    "13":2,
    "3": 5,
    "5":8,
    "7":3,
    "4":8,
    "10":7
}
```

**Desired result:**

```
{
    "3": 5,
    "5":8,
    "7":3,
    "4":8,
    "10":7
}
```

Comment: What if there's a tie for fifth place?

Comment: shoud be kept @Kevin

Comment: So just to verify, an example: if your input is a 100-item dictionary whose values are all the same, the result should also be 100 items, because they're all tied. Right?

Comment: @kevin good point yes i should keep all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounting for ties:

```
val = sorted(d.values(), reverse=True)[4]
res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v >= val}

print(res)

{'3': 5, '5': 8, '7': 3, '4': 8, '10': 7}
```

**Explanation**

- Calculate the 5th highest value using `sorted` with `reverse=True`. Remember indexing begins at `0` so index with `[4]`.
- Use a dictionary comprehension to select all items from your dictionary where value is greater than the calculated value.

**Optimisation**

A more efficient method, as pointed out by @Chris_Rands, is to use `heapq` to calculate the 5th highest value:

```
import heapq

val = heapq.nlargest(5, d.values())[-1]
res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v >= val}
```

Comment: It is probably better to calculate `val` with `heapq.nlargest(5, d.values())[-1]` (assuming `n` is quite small relative to `len(d)`)

Answer (score 1):

```
from  collections import Counter
dict(Counter(your_dict).most_common(5))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'10': 7, '3': 5, '4': 8, '5': 8, '7': 3}
```

Comment: @jpp Ties means when values are same for different keys?

Comment: @jpp I think it is handling the case. Look for keys '5' and '4'. They have same values.So it will work for ties as well.

Comment: try `d = {"1": 1, "12": 3, "13":2, "3": 5, "5":8, "7":3, "4":8, "10":7}`

Comment: {'10': 7, '12': 3, '3': 5, '4': 8, '5': 8} @jpp '12':3 is included.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear.. both `'7': 3` & `'12': 3` should be in your result.